# Prevent some hbm files from auto creating/altering tables in hbms

Tags: java, hibernate, hbm2ddl, hbm

I have some tables which are created/altered(updated) from outside of my application, and in my application i only want to execute queries on those tables. So my application should not be able to create/alter these tables, but it has some hbm files which should create/alter tables.
So my question is: How can i prevent (only) some of hbm files from creating/altering their tables?